# Stop fixed div on specific DIV

Tags: css, fixed, sticky

I have this code to make my sidebar sticked when scrolling down. However, this let the sidebar scroll to the bottom of the page, which overlaps other elements on the site.

```js
$(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var s = $("#counter");
    var pos = s.position();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"> 
  <div id="counter">
   * php dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' ); *
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I have searched for an hour now without finding any solution. I want the sidebar to stop being sticked when the scroll reach the div **footer**.

Comment: You might want to include the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Added in first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use css to tackle this issue.
Just add padding from bottom equal to the height of the element at the bottom.

Suppose if you have a footer with height 50px.Then add padding-bottom:50px to the sidebar and give footer some z-index also like z-index:9 or z-index:99.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I see your point, but it doesn't work as it should. The sticked sidebar needs to be stopped exactly on the beginning of footer div. This method screws up the height of the start for the sidebar. Thanks

Comment: Then remove padding-bottom and add bottom:-50px also remove top property if there is any only add bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I made it work by adding position:relative to the footer. Now the sidebar goes behind the footer, and it works as it should.